# lightning:map doesnt work on callout in init

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

When I try to set location from data that I'm fetching during init map is just not rendering at all. I tried to move whole stuff into onRender but it also fails (goes into infinite loop). Anyone have any idea how make it work? Or how to replace it with something else?

```
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getGeoLocation");
        action.setParams({"recordId": component.get("v.recordId")});

        // Configure response handler
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
                component.set('v.data', parsed);

            } else {
                console.log(response.getError());
                console.log('Problem getting data, response state: ' + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        component.set('v.zoomLevel', 16);
    },

    onRender: function(component, event, helper){
        var data = component.get('v.data');

        var mapMarkers = [
            {
                location: {
    'Latitude': data.Location__latitude__s,
    'Longitude': data.Location__longitude__s

                },
                title: data.Name

            }
        ]
    component.set('v.mapMarkers', mapMarkers); 


    }

})
```

Version with everything in init:

```
({
    init: function (component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getGeoLocation");
        action.setParams({"recordId": component.get("v.recordId")});

        // Configure response handler
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if(state === "SUCCESS") {
                var parsed = JSON.parse(response.getReturnValue());
        var mapMarkers = [
            {
                location: {
                   'Latitude': parsed.Location__latitude__s,
                   'Longitude': parsed.Location__longitude__s

                },
                title: parsed.Name

            }
        ]

        component.set('v.mapMarkers', mapMarkers); 


            } else {
                console.log(response.getError());
                console.log('Problem getting Pump, response state: ' + state);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
        component.set('v.zoomLevel', 16);
    },

})
```

Comment: Are you saying `component.set('v.mapMarkers', mapMarkers);` is not working?

Comment: It works when marker data is static. So if I use it outside callback function and set some example values, it works fine. Otherwise map is either not rendering at all, or rendering with some default place in center (somewhere over north cost of Australia :P)

Comment: You may like to verify if the variable `parsed` is returning value or not. Put some console.log to verify that. Also I don't think you really need the condition `parsed != undefined`.

Comment: Yeah that last part is leffover. And I positivly confirmed that parsed have correct values

Comment: Isn't this again assigning empty values at the end of the function -- `component.set('v.mapMarkers', '');`?

Comment: Updated my codesnippet and removed all of the garbage. Yeah it was (although it runned acutally before set in callback). Current code snippet still doesnt work

Comment: you could try using an aura:if tag around the map that gets set to true after you populate the mapMarkers attribute